# Keyboard navigation with JQuery not acting as expected

Tags: jquery, list, keyboard

I followed the following tutorial which is supposed to allow keyboard scrolling and selecting through unordered list items -> [Tutorial](http://www.marcofolio.net/webdesign/advanced_keypress_navigation_with_jquery.html.)

I'm using it alongside the suggestion box as described -> [Suggestion Box](http://www.marcofolio.net/webdesign/a_fancy_apple.com-style_search_suggestion.html)

PLEASE NOTE THAT I FOLLOWED BOTH THESE TUTS TO THE LETTER WITH THE EXCEPTION OF CHANGING ID's and NAMES.

It does seem to work (when I key down the hover effect does show), but it immediately disappears after I let go of the key. If I keep the down arrow pressed, it will scroll to the bottom of my list but once the key is released the hover effect disappears immediately. JQuery is by no means my strong suite so I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong. I'm using the code exactly as described in the tutorial. I've only changed the #menu to #suggestions as this is what my div is named.

Here is the code however:

```
   var currentSelection = 0;
var currentUrl = '';

google.load("jquery", "1.3.1");
google.setOnLoadCallback(function()
{
    // Register keypress events on the whole document
    $(document).keypress(function(e) {
        switch(e.keyCode) { 
            // User pressed "up" arrow
            case 38:
                navigate('up');
            break;
            // User pressed "down" arrow
            case 40:
                navigate('down');
            break;
            // User pressed "enter"
            case 13:
                if(currentUrl != '') {
                    window.location = currentUrl;
                }
            break;
        }
    });

    // Add data to let the hover know which index they have
    for(var i = 0; i < $("#suggestions ul li a").size(); i++) {
        $("#suggestions ul li a").eq(i).data("number", i);
    }

    // Simulote the "hover" effect with the mouse
    $("#suggestions ul li a").hover(
        function () {
            currentSelection = $(this).data("number");
            setSelected(currentSelection);
        }, function() {
            $("#suggestions ul li a").removeClass("itemhover");
            currentUrl = '';
        }
    );
});

function navigate(direction) {
    // Check if any of the menu items is selected
    if($("#suggestions ul li .itemhover").size() == 0) {
        currentSelection = -1;
    }

    if(direction == 'up' && currentSelection != -1) {
        if(currentSelection != 0) {
            currentSelection--;
        }
    } else if (direction == 'down') {
        if(currentSelection != $("#suggestions ul li").size() -1) {
            currentSelection++;
        }
    }
    setSelected(currentSelection);
}

function setSelected(menuitem) {
    $("#suggestions ul li a").removeClass("itemhover");
    $("#suggestions ul li a").eq(menuitem).addClass("itemhover");
    currentUrl = $("#suggestions ul li a").eq(menuitem).attr("href");
}
```

Can anybody perhaps assist me in this matter please?

Comment: Try on `keydown` instead..

Comment: Did that as well. Didn't solve this problem. Does the exact same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try this plugin http://plugins.jquery.com/keyscroll/ , allows scrolling up and down through lists